# How to convert Rcpp::List to std::vector<double>

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I'm a newcomer in the field of R langauge, but I need to compute singular value decomposition via irlba in my C++ code. For this purpose I use RInside lib.

```
RInside R(argc, argv); 
std::string cmd = "S<-diag(3)";
R.parseEval(cmd);
R.parseEval("B<-svd(S,nu=dim(S)[1],nv=dim(S)[2])");
Rcpp::List V ((SEXP)R.parseEval("B$v"));
```

Now I need to convert my results from Rcpp::List with singular vectors to std::vector

Question:
What is the best way to convert results of performing svd to the std::vector?

How can I transform my input matrix written as std::vector to the format appropriate for using it as an input parameter for svd function in irlba?

Comment: You want `Rcpp::as< std::vector<double> >(V)`, I believe. But why are you storing the result of `B$v` in an `Rcpp::List` -- isn't that itself a `NumericMatrix` (`NumericVector`)?

Comment: Thanks very much, it really works. But I still don't know how to transform std::vector to "matrix type for R language". I mean, that when I use
 std::vector<double> x(9, 0.f);
 x[0] = 1;
 x[4] = 1;
 x[8] = 1;
 R["S"] = Rcpp::wrap(x);
 R.parseEval("B<-svd(S,nu = 3, nv = 3)"); 
It interprets S variable as a vector instead of square matrix and performs svd for vector. How could I explicitly specify that it is a 3*3 matrix?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To go from C++ types to R objects, you can use `wrap`. The way I usually construct `NumericMatrix`s from a `std::vector<double>` is like so:

```
// with x as a std::vector<double>
using namespace Rcpp;
NumericVector m = wrap(x); // wrap x into an R object
m.attr("dim") = Dimension(<num_rows>, <num_cols>); // set the dimensions
```

with `<num_rows>` and `<num_cols>` chosen based on your desired dimensions. `m` should then be usable as an R matrix.

In general, you can use `as<T>` to go from R types to C++ types, and `wrap` to go from C++ types to R types. See section 3 of the [Rcpp-Introduction vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-introduction.pdf) for some more information.